# Is it Possible to declare Cursor within IF Condition in MySQL UDF

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

Is it possible for me to Declare cursor inside if statement?

if possible how could i make it?

because i just made cursor like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_test`(
    ProductID BIGINT(20)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)

BEGIN
DECLARE PrductDiscValue DECIMAL(10, 2);
DECLARE DiscType INT(1);
DECLARE DiscValue DESIMAL(10,2);

IF ProductID != 0 THEN 
    SET PrductDiscValue = (SELECT Discountvalue, DiscountType FROM discount WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ProductID,DiscIDs);
END IF;

RETURN ProductDiscountValue(1);
```

But this is not working. So, I do the following

```
IF ProductID != 0 THEN 
    DECLARE PrductDiscValue CURSOR FOR SELECT Discountvalue, DiscountType FROM discount WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ProductID,DiscIDs;
END IF;

OPEN ProductDiscountValue;
FETCH ProductDiscountValue INTO DiscValue, DiscType; 
RETURN DiscValue;
END
```

And this gives me error ::

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE ProdDiscValue CURSOR FOR SELECT Discountvalue, DiscountType FROM discount' at line 16.

I need the both DiscValue and DiscType for different calculation.

Any Help would be appreciate

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Please, use it:

BEGIN

```
IF test = true THEN
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE ats_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct ats_id FROM ats_eb ats where  ats.year = year and  ats.edition_shortname = edition;
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE ats_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct ats_id FROM ats_eb ats where  ats.year = year and  ats.edition_shortname = edition;
    END;
END IF;
```

END

Comment: you are super star

Answer (score 3):

even I never used CURSOR so far in MySQL, But what I found is that , it is clearly mentioned on **[MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)**

> Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after
>   variable and condition declarations.

if you want to use that cursor on some condition then you must use **FETCH CURSOR** syntax in **IF** condition

below are some good tutorial which will describe the cursor in details:

[CURSOR in mySQL stored procedure](http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/)

[MySQL CURSOR Tutorial](http://www.techflirt.com/mysql-cursor-tutorial/)