# Cursor Declaration in ELSE IF block in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want know, **can we declare cursor in ELSE IF block**?
when i do this i found error 
**missing  subclause or other element before 'declare'** .my code is

```
 if State is NOT NULL
    then
    declare t cursor for select *from student;//this line has error 
    declare continue handler for NOT FOUND set str=1;
    else
    declare t cursor for select *from student;
    end if;
```

why??

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **NO**. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html) clearly says:

> Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after
>   variable and condition declarations.

A similar [[bug: 15809]](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15809)(*which eventually was not*) was reported but it was closed with the following answer:

> Thank you for a problem report. Sorry, but I do not think it is a bug.
>   The problem is that cursor should be declared, and all declarations
>   are at the beggining of SP or a block.
>
> Please, read (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html):
>
> "Cursors must be declared before declaring handlers, and variables and
>   conditions must be declared before declaring either cursors or
>   handlers."
>
> And, even more clearly
>   (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html):
>
> "The DECLARE statement is used to define various items local to a
>   routine: local variables (see Section 17.2.9, “Variables in Stored
>   Procedures”), conditions and handlers (see Section 17.2.10,
>   “Conditions and Handlers”) and cursors (see Section 17.2.11,
>   “Cursors”). SIGNAL and RESIGNAL  statements are not currently
>   supported.
>
> DECLARE may be used only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and
>   must be at its start, before any other statements."
>
> So, it is not a bug, but a documented behaviour.

Comment: if we declare cursur in between BEGIN.....END block.then can we open and fetch that cursur outside the BEGIN ....END block?

Comment: @Arunnagar:- No, that is not possible. Also what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sir,my code is : **set str_commmand='declare Sdetails cursur for select * from student'**; sir please tell me it is possible to declare cursur in a statement  in mysql.**and** if yes then how to execute this statement

Comment: @Arunnagar:- This is not how you declare the cursor. Also you should try to avoid using cursor as it has performance issues. Also if you can specify what you are trying to achieve then may be we can help(*probably without using cursor*)!

Comment: :-sir i am work on a project.and i used sql server 2012.now i use mysql server so i want to convert stored procedure of sql server to mysql server.sql server's stored procedure has cursur declaration in a stetement so i want to know it is possible to do this in mysql server. if yes then how to?

Comment: You can declare cursors inside if and else. Check this  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67657284/341117

Answer (score 1):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a **BEGIN ... END** compound
>   statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations.

[DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html)

Answer (score 0):

Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.

if you want to use that cursor on some condition then you must use FETCH CURSOR syntax in IF condition.